# Construct circle as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have to construct the circle as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ which is $\mathcal C^\infty $. The circle is given by $$\mathbb S^1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}=f^{-1}(1).$$

We have that $$df_p=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\right)=2(p_1,p_2)$$

I have a theorem that says that if $Rg(f,x)$ is constant on an open $U\supset f^{-1}(1)$, then $f^{-1}(1)$ is a submanifold. The problem is that $Rg(df_p)= 1$ if $p\neq 0$ and $Rg(df_p)=0$ if $p=0$, and since every open that contain $\mathbb S^1$ contain also $0$, it can't be a submanifold, right ?

So, how can I continue ?

Comment: It's certainly not true that every open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ that contains $\Bbb S^1$ also contains $0$; consider $\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: There are two questionable assertions: 1. Your theorem is not "if and only if"; a manifold can be "cut out" by a function whose differential is singular everywhere, e.g., $f(x, y) = x^{2}$ describes the $y$-axis (as a point set). 2. As Travis notes, there exist lots of open sets that contain the circle and do not contain the origin.

Comment: @Travis: Ok, then I can conclude. Tks,

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I never said that it's an iff. But if $Rg(df)$ then $f^{-1}(q)$ can't be a submanifold, no ? (since if it's constant it's a manifold)

Comment: It's true you didn't _explicitly_ say the theorem was iff, but "[since the rank isn't constant] the level can't be a submanifold" sounds like an implicit belief that if the rank of $df$ isn't constant along $f^{-1}(q)$, then $f^{-1}(q)$ isn't a submanifold, which isn't true. If $g(y) = e^{-1/y}$ for $y > 0$ and $g(y) = 0$ for $y \leq 0$ (so $g$ is smooth, non-negative, and not identically zero), then the $y$-axis is cut out by $f(x, y) = xg(y) + x^{3}$, though the rank of $df$ is not constant along the $y$-axis. (This example has no _direct_ bearing on your question, of course....)